# Unfinished stubbing detected

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

The error below appeared in my code when using mockito:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java:36)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

The Stack trace that caused this:

```
PageCodeBase mockPageCodeBase = Mockito.mock(PageCodeBase.class);
        Map<String, String> nn = getStringV();
        when(mockPageCodeBase.getRequestParam()).thenReturn(nn);

private Map<String, String> getStringV(){
        Map<String, String> mapV = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapV.put("selectedApplicantId", "selectedApplicantId");
        return mapV;
    }
```

did I miss any thing here

Comment: Is that the code where the exception happens? It may be in the code before or above that.

Answer (score 1):

After I removed PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ASKService.class);
declaration on @Before its works for me.